# Muti DC Alertmanager HA setup

Tags: prometheus, high-availability, prometheus-alertmanager

I have few DC clusters, each one have own set of Prometheus-es

From what I've read here 
https://www.robustperception.io/prometheus-and-alertmanager-architecture  it is important to have one alertmanager cluster to prevent alerting from each DC.
But there are few questions left:

1. Where alertmanager cluster should be located - can it be spanned over few DCs?
2. How to continue receiving alarm even when link between DCs is down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where alertmanager cluster should be located - can it be spanned over few DCs?

Yes

> How to continue receiving alarm even when link between DCs is down?

As long as the Prometheus can get to at least one alertmanager that can get to whatever sends your notifications (e.g. Pagerduty) you will receive notifications.

Comment: I expected that you'll answer the question :) Thanks Brian, for being such supportive to the community!